# How many terms of the $\sum_{n=0}^{∞}\frac {(-1)^{n+1}} n$ will approximate to .001 of $\ln 2$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Use the fact that 
$1 - \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 - ... + \frac {(-1)^{2k+1}} {2k}$  equals to more or less $\ln 2$ equals to or greater than $1 - \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 - ... + \frac {(-1)^{2k+2}} {2k +1}$ to determine how many terms of the series 
$\sum_{n=0}^{∞}\frac {(-1)^{n+1}} n$  should be added together to approximate $\ln 2$ within .001 without actually computing what $\ln 2$ is.

So far I replaced $k$ on both sides with 1 and found the difference of their results to be $- \frac 1 6$, I plan on plugging that in to find k.  I know I need to find K to figure out how many terms, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. Can anyone share their insight?

Answer (score 1):

The partial sums are alternatingly larger and smaller than $\ln2$; this shows that 
$$
|\ln2-S_k|<\frac1{k+1}
$$
where $S_k=\sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^{i+1}\frac1i$. So, $S_{1000}$ is certainly within $0.001$ of $\ln 2$.

Comment: Here is just a comment to improve the calculation.  To have an accuracy within $\epsilon>0$, it suffices to compute up to $S_{N(\epsilon)}$, where $N(\epsilon):=\left\lceil\dfrac{1}{2\epsilon}\right\rceil$.  In particular, for $\epsilon=0.001$, $N(\epsilon)=500$.  This is quite a sharp bound as $$\big|\ln(2)-S_{499}\big|\approx0.001001\,,$$ whereas $$\big|\ln(2)-S_{500}\big|\approx 0.000999\,.$$